# using statement; why is my field not set to null?

Tags: c#, using, keyword

I am trying to minimize entity framework connection context scope using "using" while at the mean time I want to be able to inject a context into my class.
I searched on internet but did not find a case like mine, or I am just doing something wrong, anyway, here is code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Dummy
{
  private IFoo ifoo;
  [Test]
  public void CreateIfNotExist()
  {
    using (var foo = GetNewIFoo())
    {
      foo.Dosomething();
    }
    Assert.IsNull(ifoo);//test fail here
  }

  [Test]
  public void NotCreateIfExist()
  {
    ifoo = new Bar();
    using (var foo = GetNewIFoo())
    {
      foo.Dosomething();
    }
    Assert.IsNull(ifoo);//test fail here
  }

  private IFoo GetNewIFoo()
  {
    if (ifoo == null)
    {
     ifoo = new Foo();//return new Foo();
    }
    return ifoo;
  }
}
```

the first test failed, with a object sequence of foo created->foo do something->foo disposed(called by using on foo) while the state variable ifoo is still type of Foo().

Second test failed, with object life sequence as same as before.

I am confused as I thought GetNewIFoo() would return a reference of ifoo and using keyword would just call dispose on ifoo?

Also, is there any good way to control context scope while maintaining ability to inject IContext ?

Comment: (clarified the title, as there are two completely unrelated uses of the `using` keyword in C#; *using statements* and *using directives*)

Comment: Ya, the first idea I saw the original title is "it will be closed soon because of exact duplicates". But indeed the question is not what I thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `Dispose()` **does not clear the references** (nor does it perform garbage collection). It simply calls the `Dispose()` method, which can (for example) close connections, files, etc - depending on the implementation. An object can be non-null and still disposed. Some objects allow you to see if an object is disposed; most don't.

Generally, if you are `using` something, you wouldn't write that variable somewhere else (i.e. you wouldn't write it as a field somewhere).

Answer (score 4):

Meaning if `using` block is in next:

```
using (var foo = GetNewIFoo())
{
    foo.Dosomething();
} // foo.Dipose() will be called automatically
```

which is the same as:

```
var foo = GetNewIFoo())
try
{
    foo.Dosomething();
}
finally
{
    foo.Dipose();
}
```

so `foo` is not `null` after `using`, but it's disposed.

---

Also:

```
using (var foo = GetNewIFoo())
{
    foo.Dosomething();
}
//^ nothing below affects ifoo!!

Assert.IsNull(ifoo); // so why reference should be null??
```

Comment: Yep that is a good point, then I am in trouble to reopen EF context connection as it is disposed

Comment: @Yuan: Please post some code. And probably in newly created question. (Approve an answer here before).

Comment: You and Marc are all correct but Marc had pin pointed the idea 1 second before you :P Thanks guys.

Comment: The idea about EF context is imagine IFoo is IContext and foo/bar are the real entity and faked one, I want my production code named "Dummy" to be able to dynamically load/create context.